# Shell script to print a range of dates with a 6 hour increment

Tags: linux, shell

I got a shell script which prints date from one given date to another with six hour difference. I need hour 00,06,12 and 18. It does perfectly that up to some dates and then prints 01,07,13,19. I can not understand what is the reason. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

start=$(date --date '1 jan 1998 00:00' +%s)
stop=$(date --date '31 dec 1998 18:00' +%s)
for t in $(seq ${start} 21600 ${stop})
    do
        idate1=`date --date @${t} +'%Y%m%d%H'`
        idate2=`date --date @${t} +'%Y%m%d'`
        iyr1=`date --date @${t} +'%Y'`
        imon1=`date --date @${t} +'%m'`
        iday1=`date --date @${t} +'%d'`
#       sleep 2s
        echo  $idate1
    done
```

Comment: You can add `+ 6 hours` to your use of the `--date` option and simply compare successive additions of `6 hours` with the `%s` format against the end date with the `%s` format.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me?  I put the following at the end to confirm :-
 grep -E '(01|07|13|19)$'  Of course life would be easier if you didn't pick a whole year as far as debugging goes :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please provide the exact code that will print for example 1998010100, 1998010106,1998010112,1998010118.....1998123100,1998123106,1998123112,1998123118 and so forth?

Comment: while I am running the code given above, for the months of may June July august September and October it is printing 01,07,13,19 instead of 00,06,12 & 18.

Comment: Sounds very much like a daylight saving time issue.
Try to set your TZ environment variable to UTC, which does not know daylight saving time.
`export TZ=UTC`

Comment: Kkeller.... that was exactly the case. Thank you so much. Bless you all.

Comment: @kkeller, That comment should be posted as an answer.